# One Promise calling an unknown (dynamic) number of async methods in sequence

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to create one Promise that, internally, calls a series of asynchronous methods in sequence and returns the results of these methods, concatenated in an ordered Array, once the last method returns.

I was trying this:

```js
const getArray = function (thisArray) {
    return new Promise ( function (resolve, reject) {
        if (thisArray.length < 3) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('adding element');
                thisArray.push(thisArray.length);
                getArray(thisArray);
            },  1000); 
        } else {
            console.log(thisArray);
            console.log('resolving');
            resolve(thisArray);
        }
    });
}

getArray([]).then(function(data) {
    console.log('thened');
    console.log(data);
})
```

but it doesn't ever calls the `then()`. How can I do this?

Comment: Some of the answers to [*How to return the response from an asynchronous call?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) address resolving a series of promises like that (and parallel ones too).

Comment: It's not clear to me how the code there relates to your description of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, you can run it. It uses recursion to guarantee sequence, and builds the array just before sending it to the resolve( . ) call, so I thought I was close to getting it to work. Perhaps not. Perhaps the whole structure is wrong.

Comment: I have updated it.

Comment: In your real scenario, don't you have existing information you're looping over? Rather than just creating things from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far off at all, you just need to be sure to call `resolve` for each `new Promise`. If you're still building the array, you pass the resulting promise from your recursive `getArray` call; otherwise, you pass the array:

```js
const getArray = function(thisArray) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (thisArray.length >= 3) {
            // All done
            resolve(thisArray);
        } else {
            // Do something async...
            setTimeout(() => {
                // ...add the result
                console.log('adding element');
                thisArray.push(thisArray.length);
                // ...and recurse
                resolve(getArray(thisArray));
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}

getArray([]).then(data => {
    console.log('done');
    console.log(data);
});
```

That's a bit cleaner if you separate the function doing the async work from `getArray`, and ensure that the function doing the async work returns a promise. For our purposes, we can just wrap `setTimeout` in a Promise wrapper:

```
const setTimeoutP = (cb, delay) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(cb());
        }, delay);
    });
};
```

then:

```
const getArray = thisArray => {
    if (thisArray.length >= 3) {
        return Promise.resolve(thisArray);
    }
    return setTimeoutP(() => {
        console.log("adding element");
        thisArray.push(thisArray.length);
    });
};
```

Live copy:

```js
const setTimeoutP = (cb, delay) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(cb());
        }, delay);
    });
};

const getArray = thisArray => {
    if (thisArray.length >= 3) {
        return Promise.resolve(thisArray);
    }
    return setTimeoutP(() => {
        console.log("adding element");
        thisArray.push(thisArray.length);
        return getArray(thisArray);
    }, 1000);
};

getArray([]).then(data => {
    console.log('done');
    console.log(data);
});
```